# Apply default conditional formatting for excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am wondering if there is a way to apply conditional formatting to all new excel files that are going to be created.

Basically, I want to apply conditional formatting for cells containing formulas. I can do it for every single worksheet but is there a way to tweak the application so that the rule applies to all workbooks that are going to be created in the future?

Comment: Nup, not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your conditional formatting (and any other things you want to make available) in a new workbook and store it in your **XlStart** folder.

To find your XlStart folder; here are instructions from Microsoft's documents (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-how-excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19):

> Any workbook, template, or workspace file that you place in the XLStart folder is automatically opened when you start Excel. To find out the path of the XLStart folder, check the Trust Center settings. To do so:

> Click File > Options, Click Trust Center, and then under Microsoft Office Excel Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings. Click Trusted Locations, and then verify the path to the XLStart folder in the list of trusted locations.

> Use an alternate startup folder Click File > Options > Advanced. Under General, in the At Startup, open all files in box, type the full path of the folder that you want to use as the alternate startup folder.

> Because Excel will try to open every file in the alternate startup folder, make sure that you specify a folder that contains only files that Excel can open.

> Note: If a workbook with the same name is in both the XLStart folder and the alternate startup folder, the file in the XLStart folder opens.

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes my life a lot easier.